# Workaround for NHibernate DB2 inexact query bug?

Tags: nhibernate, db2

Does anyone know a workaround for [NH-2436](http://216.121.112.228/browse/NH-2436)?

Basically, when you concatenate a parameter in the case of `(% || ? || %)` DB2 requires it to be cast as in `CAST((% || ? || %) AS VARCHAR(255))` which NHibernate does not do, otherwise an exception is thrown.

Is there some way to work around this and do a parameter based `LIKE` query using NHibernate against DB2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you throw fluentNhibernate, Linq, and automapping out the window I was able to work around this with a named query.